# WooCommerce REST API can't edit products

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to add this product to Woocommerce using REST API, the product gets created but without parameters, if I try to update it with name and slug it does not work. I don't get errors, it just ignore the update.

I'm using API v3.

**API call**

```
//bypass ssl validation check globally for whole application.
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

urlWooComApi = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("urlWooComApi"); 

string userWooComApi = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("userWooComApi");
string pwdWooComApi = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("pwdWooComApi");
//var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat };
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat };

RestRequest req = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
req.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
req.Resource = "products";
req.AddQueryParameter("consumer_key", userWooComApi);
req.AddQueryParameter("consumer_secret", pwdWooComApi);

var jsonProdotti = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstProdotti.Take(1), settings);
req.AddParameter("application/json", jsonProdotti, ParameterType.RequestBody);


RestClient client = new RestClient(urlWooComApi);
IRestResponse resp = client.Execute(req);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resp.ErrorMessage)) throw new Exception($"{resp.ErrorMessage}");
reasons = resp.Content;
if (resp.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Created) throw new Exception($"{reasons}");


JsonDeserializer deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
var Prod = deserializer.Deserialize<wcProduct>(resp);

return Prod;
```

**JSON**

```
[{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "WILSON REVOLVE 17 BK SPTM€25",
  "slug": "WRZ906900 ",
  "permalink": null,
  "date_created": "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/",
  "date_created_gmt": "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/",
  "date_modified": "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/",
  "date_modified_gmt": "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/",
  "type": null,
  "status": null,
  "featured": false,
  "catalog_visibility": null,
  "description": "WILSON REVOLVE 17 BK SPTM€25",
  "short_description": null,
  "sku": "WRZ906900 ",
  "price": null,
  "regular_price": "200,000000",
  "sale_price": null,
  "date_on_sale_from": null,
  "date_on_sale_from_gmt": null,
  "date_on_sale_to": null,
  "date_on_sale_to_gmt": null,
  "on_sale": false,
  "purchasable": true,
  "total_sales": 0,
  "virtual": false,
  "downloadable": false,
  "downloads": null,
  "download_limit": 0,
  "download_expiry": 0,
  "external_url": null,
  "button_text": null,
  "tax_status": null,
  "tax_class": null,
  "manage_stock": false,
  "stock_quantity": 0,
  "backorders": null,
  "backorders_allowed": false,
  "backordered": false,
  "low_stock_amount": null,
  "sold_individually": false,
  "weight": null,
  "dimensions": null,
  "shipping_required": false,
  "shipping_taxable": false,
  "shipping_class": null,
  "shipping_class_id": 0,
  "reviews_allowed": false,
  "average_rating": null,
  "rating_count": 0,
  "upsell_ids": null,
  "cross_sell_ids": null,
  "parent_id": 0,
  "purchase_note": null,
  "categories": null,
  "tags": null,
  "images": null,
  "attributes": null,
  "default_attributes": null,
  "variations": null,
  "grouped_products": null,
  "menu_order": 0,
  "price_html": null,
  "related_ids": null,
  "meta_data": null,
  "stock_status": null,
  "_links": null
}]
```

I tried changing theme and deactivating all the plugins except WooCommerce but I still get the same result. I can create the product but I’m not able to modify it thourgh API rest. And even when I creat it it ignores my parameters. I’m following the official API documentation and I tried both v2 and v3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to send every available field just the ones that you are using. And you can't use read-only fields in the requests. You can see which fields are read-only here https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-properties

Your request should look like this

```
{
  "name": "FLUYD SHORTY LADY 2.0MM",
  "type": "variable",
  "sku": "000031",
  "regular_price": "0",
  "manage_stock": true,
  "stock_quantity": 0,
  "attributes": [{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "size",
    "position": 0,
    "visible": true,
    "variation": true,
    "options": ["L", "M", "S", "XL", "XS"]
  }]
}
```